# Install Sublime linter html-tidy on windows 7

Tags: html, sublimetext3, htmltidy

I am new to programming. I am installing sublime linter 3 html-tidy on windows 7. I read the documentation of sublime-linter for html-tidy and previous QAs in stackoverflow about html-tidy, but I can't fully understand the brief steps for the html-tidy linter.

I have succeeded on installing js, css, php sublime linter, but I can't successfully install html-tidy linter. After I did the following steps, I tried writing HTML with a missing tag, but it doesn't show any error.

The following steps that I've done:
 1. Install npm
 2. Set Node environment in Path in Windows System Variables
 3. From Sublime Package Control, Install sublime linter
 4. Download tidy.exe and tidy.dll, and set both files path in environment path in Windows System Variables as well
 5. From Sublime Package Control, Install Sublimelinter HTML tidy
 6. From npm command prompt, I did the same way of installing js css linter, this time I write "npm install -g html-tidy", and results in "-- html-tidy@0.0.1"

Yet it's not working. Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you looked at the following link? https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeLinter-html-tidy

Comment: It's solved! My mistake. Previously I put the wrong path in the environment variables path, including the .exe and .dll files like "C:\Users\Herza\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\Tidy\libtidy.dll;  C:\Users\Herza\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\Tidy\libtidy.exe;"
When I change it with just the PATH OF FOLDER where both files are stored, like "C:\Users\Herza\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\Tidy\", it works! Thank you very much!